# Can this XML be represented in CSV - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml, csv

I have following structure of an XML can we convert this into a CSV(ideally for Objective-C)

```
<root>
 <Parent>
  <Name>somename</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
  <Child>
    <ChildItem1>somevalue</ChildItem1>
    <ChildItem2>somevalue</ChildItem2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <ChildItem1>somevalue</ChildItem1>
    <ChildItem2>somevalue</ChildItem2>
  </Child>
 </Parent>
 <Parent>
  <Name>somename</Name>
  <Age>20</Age>
  <Child>
    <ChildItem1>somevalue</ChildItem1>
    <ChildItem2>somevalue</ChildItem2>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <ChildItem1>somevalue</ChildItem1>
    <ChildItem2>somevalue</ChildItem2>
  </Child>
 </Parent>
</root>
```

The problem i am facing is with the List formation of the  nodes.

Thanks in advance

Edited : My Problem is i need to get the XML above as a result of CSV/Excel spread sheet, but dont know how to create such a format of cells in it.

Comment: Please explain better what exact problem do you have?

Comment: Hi Max, added some more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV describes a **grid** of data.

XML describes a **tree** of data.

The only XML that could be directly converted to CSV is one with a root node, containing one or more elements of the same type, each of which contained the same number and types of elements as children.

This XML doesn't fit that criteria, so you would need to come up with explicit rules to convert the data structure to CSV and back. If every parent element contains exactly two child elements (which is unlikely in real data, but holds for the example) then you could just flatten the children.

Comment: I too thought so, thanks for that detailed explanation, so this would mean the CSV is ruled out completely for my requirement , suppose i need to convert from the Excel spread sheet to the required xml will that be eligible, i know that MS Office provides this facility.